# changing allowInvalid to false for a field based on a checkbox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a text field in extjs grid like this:

```
part : {
  fieldLabelToken: 'label.Structure.InstallRemoveItem.Part',
  mapping : 'removedPart.part',
  ref : '../../../removedPartField',      allowInvalid : true,
  textOnly :config.textOnly,
  listeners: {
    'select':function(combo,rec,index){
      if(!params.viewOnly && !config.textOnly){
        this.refOwner.removedTrackedField.setValue(rec.get("tracked"));
        this.refOwner.transformPosInfoFields(rec.get("tracked"));
        delete  this.refOwner.selectedItemId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have checkbox on the same form like this:

```
{
      fieldLabelToken: 'label.Structure.Maintained.Structuremaintenance.InstallRemoveItem.PendingPartRemove',
      mapping : 'pendingPartRemove',
      xtype: 'checkbox',
      ref : 'pendingPartRemove',
      disabled : false
    }
```

How do I change the allowInvalid of the part field to false if the InstallRemvecheckbox is clicked?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you are talking about extjs 3? The other is, one point you are talking about a grid, next about a form

Comment: its all part of grid, sorry for the form reference there..